# ios coreplot multiple y-axis

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

i have been searching for this question for an answer for 3 days but could not figure it out.

i need to add 3 scatterplots to a graph and here's my code :

```
CPTXYAxis *x = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
CPTXYAxis *lefty = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
CPTXYAxis *righty = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];

x.coordinate = CPTCoordinateX;
lefty.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
righty.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;

CPTAxisSet *axisSetTmp = [[CPTAxisSet alloc] init];
```

for initializations and creating 3 differend plotspaces like :

```
float xAxisMin = 0;
float xAxisMax = 350;
float yAxisMin = 0;
float yAxisMax = 50;

// We modify the graph's plot space to setup the axis' min / max values.
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xAxisMax - xAxisMin)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMax - yAxisMin)];
x.plotSpace = plotSpace;
```

and finally creating my plot like :

```
CPTScatterPlot *plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
plot.dataSource = self;
plot.identifier = @"mainplot";
plot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
plot.plotSymbol = nil;
plot.plotSpace = plotSpace;
```

and when i run this , 3 lines are added but i got only 1 y-axis. could not figure out the problem.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Did you add the new axes to the graph?

   ```
   graph.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, lefty, righty, nil];
   ```
2. If all of the axes and plots will have the same plot ranges, you can use the same plot space for all of them. A new graph starts with one you can use (`defaultPlotSpace`). Use the `-addPlotSpace:` method to add additional plot spaces to the graph.

Comment: i have tried that and i now have the solution , it includes your answer also and i found out that i have made a mistake but now clearing it out with the sample app from coreplottest but it is written for mac , i am now porting it to ios :) thanks for your support :)